# How can I modify this validation logic to be able to allow characters and some special characters too to be entered?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, user-interface, angular6

Currently, only characters are allowed to be entered in field else it throws the error mentioned below in code. How can I modify this logic to be able to add letters as well as some special characters like hyphen, apostrophe etc.?

```
    function NameValidate(control: FormControl) {
  if (typeof control.value !== 'string' || !/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/g.test(control.value)) {
    return {
      error: 'Only characters allowed'
    };
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the key here is the if-statement

```
if (typeof control.value !== 'string' || !/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/g.test(control.value))
```

This one says essentially "if the control value is not a string OR does not match the regular expression `/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/`, return an error.

So, to allow also special charachters, you need to adjust the regex to allow for those. For example, to allow hyphens, change the regex to `/^[a-zA-Z\s-]+$/` (note the added `-` inside the brackets.